# why __thread gives linker error when printf statement is used?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, sparc, thread-local-storage

Here is my sample program,

```
int main()
{
   static __thread int a;

   printf("\n %d",a);

   return 0;
}
```

In this program, when printf statement is removed, it is linking fine.
When printf statement is included, it gives the following linker error

```
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_TLS_LE_HIX22: file /var/tmp//ccwb2Cxc.o: symbol <unknown>: bad symbol type SECT: symbol type must be TLS
```

PROCESSOR: SUN-SPARC
OS: UNIX

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is a known issue of Sun linker since 2006. Does it work for you if you copy the integer to a local (non-thread)?